# OAuth domain with a custom port in a dev environment?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, oauth2, registration

I have an app for which the OAuth domain is `example.com`

However, the domain for dev environment is `example.com:8000`

When trying to authorize the website, Stack Exchange replies with an error specifying that `redirect_uri` don't match the registered OAuth domain.

The problem is, in app configuration I can't register an OAuth domain with a port.

Knowing that I'd like to avoid falling back to using `localhost`, what could be done to make authorization work with a port in the `redirect_uri`?

Comment: okay - this means the port feature is not implemented yet - I ended up accessing `dev` with no port

Comment: This is (re)fixed.  See the linked (duplicate) question.